# Dynamically add columns and adapt schema to it

Tags: dynamic, sap-data-services

If my source table keeps getting one column added to it at a time, how do I map the new column to my query/source?

It is different from slowly changing dimension, as it is not records that are changing, but the number of columns itself, i.e. the schema.

How do I design a job to do this? Any solution is fine, even if it requires custom functions, scripts, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective it is not possible. This is a use case of sql injection (i.e. somehow you have to play with the ATL or repository metadata) which SAP I bet would never suggest. I think Pentaho and Talend Integration does indeed support this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

According to me by using template tables it can be possible.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example?